# Which command should I use to open an MP3 file?

Tags: command-line, mp3

Which command should I use to open an MP3 file? For example, "abcd.mp3"

```
hamza@ubuntu:/media/hamza/Elements/mmc$ cd abcd.mp3
bash: cd: abcd.mp3: Not a directory
```

Answer (score 11):

If you want to use the App set as preferred, from the directory containing the MP3 file, use `xdg-open`:

```
xdg-open abcd.mp3
```

From `man xdg-open`:

```
xdg-open - opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application
```

If you know the application you want the MP3 file to be opened with, for example, `rhythmbox`:

```
rhythmbox abcd.mp3
```

or [VLC media player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player):

```
vlc abcd.mp3
```

Comment: if you don't have `xdg-open`, you may have `gnome-open`

Comment: @CiprianTomoiaga `gnome-open` comes with `libreoffice-gtk`, `xdg-open` comes with `xdg-utils`..it should come by default in Ubuntu..

Answer (score 8):

`cd` means "change directory". A file is not a directory so a `cd` will not work on your mp3. To open a `.mp3 you need to start a music or video player. The method @heemayl uses will open the player you have set as the default.

If you want you can also use `aplay`. The command

```
aplay abcd.mp3
```

will play the mp3 from command line and stop when it is done playing. "aplay" is probably the lightest music player around since it does not have a GUI (and can also work on a server >:-D )

Comment: `aplay` does **not** play mp3 files. It can play voc, wav, raw and au files.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run an MP3  file with a particular application, then run it like:

```
 application_name audio_file_name
```

For example, if you want to run in the [MPlayer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPlayer) application then install it using:

```
 sudo apt-get install mplayer
```

Then run the audio file using the command:

```
 mplayer  abcd.mp3
```

or

```
 sudo apt-get install mpg123
 mpg123 abcd.mp3
```

or

```
 sudo apt-get install sox
 play abcd.mp3
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install vlc 
vlc abcd.mp3
```